# Some Japanese dictionaries (e.g. 大辞林, 大辞泉, and 明鏡国語辞典) use this inverted triangle outline symbol (▽) for some kanji compounds. What does it mean?

Tags: readings, dictionary, symbols

It doesn't apply to all the words, just some. Here are examples of words from that are marked with that symbol

- 悪い　(with reading にくい): [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/166457/m0u/%E6%86%8E%E3%81%84/); [大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%86%8E%E3%81%84)
- 面倒くさい　(with reading めんどくさい): [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/264709/m0u/%E3%82%81%E3%82%93%E3%81%A9%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/); [大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%81%E3%82%93%E3%81%A9%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)
- 皆 (with reading みんな): [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/214380/m0u/%E3%81%BF%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA/); [大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BF%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA)
- 判る・解る (with reading わかる): [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/237767/m0u/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B/);　[大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B)

The thing is even for the same word, 大辞林 and 大辞泉 places the ▽ symbol at different positions.

For your convenience, here are 2 cropped screenshots to illustrate what I mean:

1. From 大辞林

   [image: 大辞林]
2. From 大辞泉

   [image: 大辞泉]

Apparently 明鏡国語辞典 uses this symbol too. Here's a screenshot for 解る・判る from an EPWING viewer.

[image]

As far as I know, 広辞苑 doesn't use this symbol. See below

[image]

---

As I'm typing this, I noticed a pattern: the symbol seems to indicate that the reading is either non-standard or not-so-common for that particular kanji. Several kanji references seem to support this interpretation.

Take 悪 for example, [kakijun](http://kakijun.jp/page/aku200.html) mentions "にく(む)[常用外]", and [漢字辞典ネット](http://www.kanjijiten.net/jiten/1601.html#k1613) labels "にく(む)" with 準1 (which I assume is the second highest level in 漢検?).　Same for 判る and 解る, whereas みんな and ど aren't listed as reading for 皆 and 倒 (perhaps those are more colloquial?).

It's just that 大辞泉 and 大辞林 uses different convention: for 大辞泉 it's the kanji to the right of ▽, for 大辞林 it's the kanji to the left of ▽.

Am I going in the right direction with this interpretation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific conventions in specific dictionaries, not about the Japanese language.

Comment: I think some peripheral questions about things like dictionaries would be fine on this site, personally.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a reasonable enough question. In a way, I feel like it's still related to Japanese in that knowing dictionary convention allows for deeper understanding of the language ("oh, this kanji has a ▽ next to it; now I know that this is a non-standard reading"). Maybe that's just me, though!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Am I going in the right direction with this interpretation?

You got it, friend! [大辞林曰く](http://www.weblio.jp/sanseido.jsp)、

> 【　】の中【なか】の漢字【かんじ】が「常用【じょうよう】漢字【かんじ】表【ひょう】」にないものには「 ▼ 」、その漢字が「常用漢字表」にはあるが見出【みだ】しに相当【そうとう】する音訓【おんくん】が示【しめ】されていないものには「 ▽ 」を漢字の右肩【みぎかた】に付【ふ】した。
>   If a given kanji isn't part of the 常用漢字 list, it'll be marked with a ▼. If it *is* part of the 常用漢字 list but uses a non-standard reading, a ▽ will be placed on its right side.

Same deal on the [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/help/jn/09_04.html):

> ▽  常用漢字表にない音訓
>   ▽  Non-standard reading of a 常用漢字

So yes, **the ▽ symbol indicates a non-standard kanji reading**. And yeah, it looks like both dictionaries choose opposite sides of the characters to place the symbol on.

Comment: (slaps my own head) ah, I never knew 凡例 has such information.

Comment: Sure does! Whenever I have a question about dictionary formatting, the legend is always my first stop. They're usually very comprehensive and informative. :)