# all the readings of 父

Tags: kanji

I know that 父 means father and it's readed "chichi". I thought the other reading of it was "tou" since I've heard many times o tou san to refer to a father. But according to this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_j%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji the readings of 父 are "fu" and "chichi". Is that list incomplete or does tou of o-tou-san written with other kanji?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that list on Wikipedia is incomplete. The article says:

> The readings presented here are those noted in the official Jōyō table. [2]

And [2] refers to [this official Joyo kanji list](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf) (PDF).

This PDF actually lists many special and/or jukujikun readings in the notes (備考) and the appendix, but those special readings are not included in the article on English Wikipedia.

[image]

What's written on the fourth (備考) column is omitted.

お父さん is a reading which is both very common and "official", but there are actually many other readings not listed in the official joyo kanji list. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17894/5010).